# Update labels from unwind segue

Tags: swift, unwind-segue

I'm trying to change the labels of a viewController after a certain action is taken from a modal view which triggers an unwind segue.

Once unwind segue happens the labels of the current view (the one which the modal was covering) should be changed.

My current attempt at doing this is resulting in a "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error. Here is the code:

```
class DataViewController: UIViewController {

var experiment: NSDictionary? 
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bodyLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var tlRightLine: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var tlLeftLine: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var brRightLine: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var brLeftLine: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var bodyTest: UITextView!

@IBAction func removeExperimentSegue(unwindSegue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    removeExperiment = true
    titleLabel.text = "Done"
    bodyLabel.text = "Done"
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)        
    if let dict: NSDictionary = experiment {
        if let title = dict.objectForKey("title") as? String {
            self.titleLabel!.text = title
        }
        if let body = dict.objectForKey("body") as? String {
            self.bodyTest!.text = body
        }
    } else {
        self.titleLabel!.text = ""
        self.bodyLabel!.text = ""
    }
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue now.  Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did! I ended up using a global boolean variable. I set it true on the initial load of the menu and then had it flip to false during the unwind segue.

```
var removeExperiment = false

class DataViewController: UIViewController { 

 @IBAction func removeExperimentSegue(unwindSegue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    removeExperiment = true
}

if removeExperiment == true {
        doneLabel.text = "You've completed this experiment. You won't see it again unless you hit 'Reset' from the Home menu."
    }

}
```

Hope that helps!